# Marshaling Struct Array with Strings Between c# and c++. Strings are empty

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, struct, marshalling

I am having the most difficult time marshaling this struct between C# and C++.
What makes it very hard to troubleshoot is that SOMETIMES the strings are populated with data (wtf), but most of the time they are not.

I've tried sending over an Array of structs as well as a IntPtr, but the results are similar, the strings in the struct are almost always empty and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in the marshaling. The code is posted below. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit*** 
Turns out the problem was on the C++ side and all the marshaling stuff was correct. Thanks for the tip Hans. ***

C++:

```
#pragma pack (push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    char FirmwareVers[FS_MAX_FIRMWARE_VER];
    char SerialNum[FS_MAX_SERIAL_NUM];
    char HardwareVers[FS_MAX_HW_VER];
    ULONG StatusFlags;
    int LMIndex; 
} FS_LMON_STATUS, *PFS_LMON_STATUS;


DllExport int _stdcall FS_GetLMs(PFS_LMON_STATUS pLaunchMonInfo, int MaxLaunchMons, int *pNumLaunchMons)
{
  int Cnt;
  FS_LMON_STATUS LMStatus;

    if(!g_IsInitalized)
        return FS_NOT_INITALIZED;

    *pNumLaunchMons = 0;

    if(MaxLaunchMons == 0)
        return FS_ERROR;

    for(Cnt = 0; Cnt < MAX_LM_CONNECTIONS; Cnt++)
    {
        if(g_CreatedClasses.pLMList->GetLMStatus(Cnt, &LMStatus) != FS_SUCCESS)
            continue;

        if(LMStatus.LMIndex != INVALID_LM_INDEX)
        {
            memcpy(pLaunchMonInfo, &LMStatus, sizeof(LMStatus));
            pLaunchMonInfo++;
            (*pNumLaunchMons)++;
            MaxLaunchMons--;

            if(MaxLaunchMons == 0)
            {
                return FS_SUCCESS;
            }
        } 
    }
    return FS_SUCCESS;
}
```

C#:

```
        [DllImport("FSADLL", SetLastError = false)]
        private static extern int FS_GetLMs([Out] IntPtr pLaunchMonInfo, int MaxLaunchMons, ref int pNumLaunchMons);


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] //, Size = 38)]
        public struct FS_LMON_STATUS
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = FS_MAX_FIRMWARE_VER)] //10 bytes
            public string FirmwareVers;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = FS_MAX_SERIAL_NUM)] // 15 bytes
            public string SerialNum;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = FS_MAX_HW_VER)] // 5 bytes
            public string HardwareVers;

            public uint StatusFlags; //4 bytes
            public int LMIndex;     // identifies which index //4 bytes
        }


            const int max_launch_monitors = 8;
            FS_LMON_STATUS[] dev_info =  new FS_LMON_STATUS[max_launch_monitors];
            int num_launch_monitors = 0;

            IntPtr pAddr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(max_launch_monitors * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FS_LMON_STATUS)));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(dev_info, pAddr, false);

            int result = FS_GetLMs(pAddr, max_launch_monitors, ref num_launch_monitors);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Result of FS_GetLMs: " + result);

            FS_LMON_STATUS[] device_info = new FS_LMON_STATUS[max_launch_monitors];

            //Marshal.Copy(pAddr, device_info, (int)0, num_launch_monitors * (int)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FS_LMON_STATUS)));
            //Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pAddr, 0);
            //device_info = (FS_LMON_STATUS[]) Marshal.PtrToStructure(Marshal.AllocHGlobal(max_launch_monitors * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FS_LMON_STATUS[]))), typeof(FS_LMON_STATUS[]));

            if (num_launch_monitors > 0)
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("GC2 Device Found.");
            else // If there is no devices found, remove the previous device from the holder variable 
                GC2Device = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < num_launch_monitors; i++)
            {
                device_info[i] = (FS_LMON_STATUS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pAddr, typeof(FS_LMON_STATUS));
                pAddr = new IntPtr(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FS_LMON_STATUS)) + pAddr.ToInt64());
            }

            //*** There will only ever be 1 device in the list until the old SDK is fixed ***
            for (int lm_index = 0; lm_index < num_launch_monitors; lm_index++)
            {
                if (device_info[lm_index].StatusFlags != LM_STATUS_DISCONNECTED)
                {

                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("device_info.SerialNum: " + device_info[lm_index].SerialNum);


                    //assign each LM to a LM data structure
                    LaunchMonitor logical_device = new LaunchMonitor(inst);
                    logical_device.mLaunchMonitorType = LaunchMonitorType.LAUNCH_MONITOR_TYPE_GC2;
                    logical_device.mConnectionType = ConnectionType.USB_CONNECTION;


                    IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(device_info[lm_index]));
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(device_info[lm_index], pnt, false);
                    //Marshal.Copy(device_info[lm_index], dv_info, 0, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FS_LMON_STATUS)));

                    logical_device.mConnectionToken = pnt;
                    //GC2Devices.Add(logical_device);

                    logical_device.Serial = logical_device.GetSerialNumber();
                    GC2Device = logical_device;

                }
            }
```

Comment: `Pack = 1` cannot be correct and gives the struct the wrong size.  Delete it.  Compare the values of `sizeof(FS_LMON_STATUS)` in the C++ code with `Marshal.SizeOf(FS_LMON_STATUS)` in the C# code to double-check.

Comment: I forgot to mention that on the c++ side the pack is being set: #pragma pack (push, 1), I edited the code above to show. I'll start trying to dig into the size of the struct on the c++ side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was on the C++ side and all the marshaling stuff was correct. Thanks for the tip Hans.